# vuejs different v-ifs from a previous select

Tags: vue.js, v-model

I am trying to display two different divs according to a select options, but I am only getting the first v-if. When I select "de", I do get the first div content, but I also get it when I select fr, instead of the second div.

I can't get my head around this. Any ideas of what I am getting wrong?

This goes on inside a form:

```
    <select v-model="source" :key="source">
        <option :value="de">de</option>
        <option :value="fr">fr</option>
    </select><br><br>
<div class="characters">
    <div v-if="source === de" class="deChars" :key="source">
        <h5>Special German characters:</h5>
        <li v-for="character in deChars" :key="character">{{ character }}</li>
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="source === fr" class="frChars" :key="source">
        <h5>Special French characters:</h5>
        <li v-for="character in frChars" :key="character">{{ character }}</li>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
```

on the script section I am using the options api with the data property source=" ", and two arrays for deChars and frChars.

note: those :key="source" I added to make sure it gets read when the source value changes.

The data properties:

```
    data(){
    return {
        original: "",
        translation: "",
        source: "",
        target: "en",
        deChars: ["ä", "Ä", "é", "ö", "Ö", "ü", "Ü", "ß"],
        frChars: ["à", "â", "ç", "é", "è", "ê", "ë", "î", "ï", "ô", "û", "ü", "œ"]
    }
},
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: unless de and fr, are variables it should be `v-if="source === 'de'"`

Comment: also many letters are used in both langs, `:key`'s should be unique

Comment: Thanks Lawrence. What you say sounds about right, and de and fr are effectively not variables. However, it definitely does not work having them as strings. Whereas I do get the German characters if I have these as variables.

Comment: It seems as if the frChars array never  gets used, or maybe it's the fr value that is never set on the source. I have now added the data properties since maybe there is something wrong in the way I am declaring the data?

Comment: o.k. So here is a clue that might be key to understanding what is happening. When I have the v-if to the German characters, and v-if-else for French (as is now), it displays that  German div for both German and French options. In the same way, if I change the order, and I place the French first and the German on the v-if-else, this time I get the French div for both options. Which means that the data is being grabed. The problem seems to be about the way the code is structured?

Comment: see/test my example below your see it works, read and apply to your code what @BoussadjraBrahim's answer says, your most likely still using `:value="de"` which is wrong. it should be plain old `value="de"`, without v-bind on it.. if that doesn't work, make an edit under your exiting code with your updated code (so original question not lost), then should be able to spot any other issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the binding sign since it seems that `de` and `fr` are not declared as properties and they're just raw string :

```
  <select v-model="source" >
        <option value="de">de</option>
        <option value="fr">fr</option>
    </select>
```

then do `v-if="source === 'de'"` and `v-else-if="source === 'fr'"`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was with the select options. THe binding seemed to mess about. Once I got rid of that, it works perfectly. So thanks for that Boussadjra. However, if on the v-if I change the de and fr to strings, it does not work. WHich is why I am adding this comment as the solution.